# Requiring User to Enter Password in order to Update Profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my update user profile form, the first field asks the user to enter her current password.  When she submits the form, I verify the password before accepting the changes in other fields.  Here's how I'm currently doing this in the users controller:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.has_password?(params[:user][:password])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  else
    flash[:failure] = "Password does not match!"
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

I feel like there's a better way to do this.  For instance I could make password matching a validation in the user model.  Then formtastic would automatically handle the error message for me (as opposed to my ugly flash approach above).  I tried doing this with

```
validate :password_match?, :on => :update
```

And

```
def password_match?
  has_password(params[:user][:password])
end
```

But as suspected params is not accessible from the model.

I searched SO for 20 minutes for a way to do this, couldn't find anything that did not involve Devise or Authlogic.  I'm doing authentication from scratch (everything works fine: signin, sessions, etc.).

Please, show me the light on the better way!

Comment: If you'd used [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), this would be built in for you in the [edit user registration view](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb#L15)

Comment: Next time I'll use devise for sure.  I learned Rails recently and followed a tutorial that involved building authentication from scratch.  I've been working off that code for my project since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need devise, just use a before filter on your controller on update
On your profile controller.

```
before_filter password_match, :only => :update
```

then on the bottom as private.

```
private

def password_match
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @user.has_password?(params[:user][:password])
```

Comment: This path has taken me down a rabbit hole.  Dragging you into the context is probably not worth it, we'd have to go back and forth several times.  I'm just going to stick with my original solution.  I think it may get down to the fact that I don't know how to use errors.add properly to add a custom error to the password field.  Anyway, accepting the answer because it was a good suggestion.

Comment: Go get some coffee and rest for a second. You don't need errors.add, how about a nice flash error at the top of the screen ? simply add  a flash.now[:error] = 'The password doesn't match your current password' and that's it :)

Comment: that's actually what my original approach was, see the first code sample above.  I decided to stick with it.